# Summation algorithm for a parallel program

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, parallel-processing, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to write a parallel algorithm to be three times faster than a sequential algorithm that does essentially the same thing. Please see the pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/3DDyxfPP

***Pasted:***

Hello everyone. I'm doing an assignment for class and have the majority of it done, however I am having some problems with the math. I am trying to calculate the expression:

```
100000000
∑ (9999999/10000000)^i * i^2
i = 1
```

i goes from 1 to 10 million.
A fast sequential algorithm is given:

```
  double sum = 0.0;
  double fact1 = 0.9999999;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
  {
     sum += (fact1 * i * i);
     fact1 *= 0.9999999;
  }
```

We are supposed to implement it and verify that it works, as well as time it in release mode. I already have this done and working properly. The time is then displayed on the console.

```
 DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
 long saveticks = t.Ticks;

 double sum = 0.0;
 double fact1 = 0.9999999;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100000000; i++)
 {
    sum += (fact1 * i * i);
    fact1 *= 0.9999999;
 }

 t = DateTime.Now;
```

We then have to write a timed parallel algorithm that will beat the time, and are supposed to model it after an example parallel program. It must be at least 3 times faster than the sequential algorithm. We are to use 4 processing elements for the parallel program.

There is a hint, "After you figure out the work each processing element will do, you may need to start off the processing element with the time consuming Pow function".

for example:
Math.Pow(x,y)

"Don't use the pow function on each iteration for the parallel code, because it wont beat the time."

Here is my code for the parallel program. This does both the sequential algorithm and the parallel one and times them both.

```
 const int numPEs = 4;
 const int size = 100000000;
 static double pSum;
 static int numThreadsDone;
 static int nextid;
 static object locker1 = new object();
 static object locker2 = new object();
 static long psaveticks;
 static DateTime pt;

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
     long saveticks = t.Ticks;

     double sum = 0.0;
     double fact1 = 0.9999999;
     for (int i = 1; i <= 100000000; i++)
     {
         sum += (fact1 * (i * i));
         fact1 *= 0.9999999;
     }

     t = DateTime.Now;
     Console.WriteLine("sequential: " + ((t.Ticks - saveticks) / 100000000.0) + " seconds");
     Console.WriteLine("sum is " + sum);

     // time it
     pt = DateTime.Now;
     psaveticks = pt.Ticks;
     for (int i = 0; i < numPEs; i++)
     new Thread(countThreads).Start();

     Console.ReadKey();
 }



 static void countThreads()
 {
     int id;
     double localcount = 0;
     lock (locker1)
     {
         id = nextid;
         nextid++;
     }
     // assumes array is evenly divisible by the number of threads
     int granularity = size / numPEs;
     int start = granularity * id;

     for (int i = start; i < start + granularity; i++)
         localcount += (Math.Pow(0.9999999, i) * (i * i));

     lock (locker2)
     {
         pSum += localcount;
         numThreadsDone++;
         if (numThreadsDone == numPEs)
         {
             pt = DateTime.Now;
             Console.WriteLine("parallel: " + ((pt.Ticks - psaveticks) / 10000000.0) + " seconds");
             Console.WriteLine("parallel count is " + pSum);
         }
     }
 }
```

My problem is that my sequential program is way faster than the parallel one. There has got to be a problem with the algorithm I'm using.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: .... and your question? Have you even attempted to write a solution to it, or do you want someone to just write the thing for you?

Comment: What do I need to modify in my parallel algorithm? As of right now, it is slower than the sequential algorithm, and it should be at least 3 times faster. I tried searching online but can't find any other approaches that I am comfortable implementing.

Comment: I already wrote an algorithm to that works, but it is way slower. I am asking for advice or help on another approach to write an algorithm that is much faster.

Comment: Can someone move the code in from pastebin?  No access at work.  :-(

Comment: Describe what the purpose of the algorithm is, and supply the code in question *in* the post's text to avoid link rot.

Comment: Have you looked the example code [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx)?

Comment: I've copied the content from Pastebin and flagged the question for re-opening.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("sequential: " + ((t.Ticks - saveticks) / 100000000.0) + " seconds");
```

There are 10,000,000 ticks in one second. In the above line, you're dividing by an extra order of magnitude, 100,000,000, making your sequential execution appear to be 10 times faster than it actually is. To avoid these errors, use the appropriate fields from the .NET Framework itself; in this case, [`TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspersecond.aspx).

The main reason you're getting a slow-down is that your parallel code is much more computationally-demanding than your sequential one.

```
// Inner loop of sequential code:
sum += (fact1 * (i * i));
fact1 *= 0.9999999;

// Inner loop of parallel code:
localcount += (Math.Pow(0.9999999, i) * (i * i));
```

From a mathematical perspective, you're justified in assuming that exponentiation would be equivalent to repeated multiplication. However, from a computational perspective, the `Math.Pow` operation is much more expensive than a simple multiplication.

A way of mitigating these expensive `Math.Pow` calls would be to perform the exponentiation just once at the beginning of each thread, and then revert to using plain multiplication (like in your sequential case):

```
double fact1 = Math.Pow(0.9999999, start + 1);
for (int i = start + 1; i <= start + granularity; i++)
{
    localcount += (fact1 * (i * i));
    fact1 *= 0.9999999;
}
```

On an Intel Core i7, this gives a speedup of around 3x for your problem size.

Obligatory reminders:

- Don't use `DateTime.Now` for measuring brief time intervals. Use the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class instead.
- Don't take cross-thread time measurements. Wait for your worker threads to complete from your main thread, and take the final reading from there.

Comment: Douglas, thank you for your answer. I fixed the error with the 100 million ticks and now the timing should be accurate. I understood that Math.Pow was a more expensive operation, but was unsure on how to implement it. Your post made it very clear as to why Math.Pow should only be used at the beginning of the thread and not on each iteration. I was able to easily model this algorithm and implement it successfully. I was able to get roughly ~2.5 faster than sequential on an i7 Q720 @1.60ghz. Would you mind explaining exactly why we are using start + 1 in the parallel algorithm?

Comment: I apologize for being new and not knowing proper formatting and etiquette on the site. I really appreciate the help I am getting here. I wanted to note I understand exactly what the algorithm is doing, other than the start + 1.

Comment: Sorry for all of the comments, but would the start + 1 have anything to do with an off-by-one error?

Comment: @user2844032: Suppose that, in your sequential version, you iterate over 1–1000 (inclusive). In your parallel version, your threads were iterating over 0–249, 250–499, 500–749, and 750–999, meaning that your original code suffered from an off-by-one error. I altered your `for` loop to fix this issue.

Comment: You're observing limited speedups because your problem size is too small to amortize the initialization costs incurred from threading. If you increase your problem size by a factor of 10, your speedup should improve to around 3.5x.

Comment: Re etiquette: The only thing you need to remember (for next time) is to post your entire question on StackOverflow, rather than link to Pastebin (or another site).